# In nodejs, will function return before all callbacks within function have executed?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

```
  function A (req,res){
   db.query(sql,cb(err,results){
      //do something
   }
}
```

When I call `function A` in the code shown above, will it return before the `cb` has executed?

Comment: I hate to sound snarky, but have you tried running this?

Comment: of course.But I am confused. In this case it often will not return until the cb has executed.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily.  If `db.query` is actually asynchronous, then the answer is yes.  However, many functions with callback-style signatures are not actually asynchronous, so it is possible that `cb` will run before `A` returns.  You should not count on either order of events in general.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

You can use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to control you sync flow.